# Appending lots of csv files in folders within a folder

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

I am working on a shared network drive where I have 1 folder (main folder) containing many subfolders; 1 for each date (over 1700) and then within them csv files (results.csv) with a common name at the end (same file format). Each csv contains well over 30k rows.

I wish to read in all the csvs appending them into one dataframe to perform some minor calculations. I have used the below code. It ran for 3+ days so I quit, but looking at the dataframe it actually got 80% of the way through. But it seems inefficient as it takes ages and when I want to add the latest days file it will have to re-run again. I also only need a handful of the columns within each csv so want to use the usecols=['A', 'B', 'C'] function but not sure how to incorporate it. Could someone shed some light please on a better solution?

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

file_source = glob.glob(r"//location//main folder//**//*results.csv", recursive=True)

appended_file = []
for i in file_source:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    appended_file.append(df)
    combined=pd.concat(appended_file, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your algorithm might be faster if you put the line `combined=pd.concat(...)` outside the for loop. Also generating a big CSV file from many smaller CSV files is generally much faster when you use command line tools.

Comment: I would test how long does it take to just read the files using Python builtins, without pandas. You can use something like https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm to keep track of the progress. It shows ETA etc. so you should see if the files reading is the bottleneck here.

Comment: Oh silly mistake from me. New line  and it ran in less than an hour. Thank you.